# What happens when you delete a comment and re-add it?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

From time to time, I delete comments that are no longer editable(expired past 5 minutes) to amend them with the same comment, just edited. This normally happens when I revisit a question and realize past the 5 minute mark that I had more to add.

Does this result in another notification being sent to the user it is targeted to? On that same note, does editing a comment result in notifications being sent to the target user?

If the former does result in a notification while the latter does not, why don't/shouldn't comment edits result in a notification to the target user?

Comment: You can only edit a comment within 5 minutes of posting it, so sending double notifications for what is most likely a typo correction doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: Moderators can edit comments at any time, but that is also rather rare and isn't likely to be for anything other than style or formatting.

Comment: @AnnaLear ah, I see. There are cases where substantial edits may and do occur though, and if users are sufficiently active it is possible to miss this. Maybe I am just thinking about too fine a detail ;) <- would you consider this a substantial edit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it results in another notification, but the notification on the deleted comment will be removed.

So if the user never read the first notification, he'll only receive one.